# Professor said we should meet again, but never answered my email

Tags: undergraduate, research-undergraduate

Recently I tried to join a lab as an undergrad and do a research project next semester. I e-mailed the professor and he arranged an interview. Interview was pretty normal, and we talked about an available project he had. At the end, he said we should meet again in August to talk more about the project.

Since the interview I have followed up several times, trying to arrange this meeting. But he never responded to my e-mails, and now I'm just confused... Should I keep waiting? Or did he just change his mind and decide to ignore me instead of telling me that. (If this is the case then it is really a d**k move. I have been spending a lot of time reading relevant papers and studying his project for the past month or so.)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: How long time did you wait?

Comment: @user199 two three weeks or so

Comment: Then, the possibility that your email goes to unknown spam box is less as he responded your email and arranged meeting. Why don’t you look forward with another opportunities, he might have received better candidate than you. Don’t wait unless he mentioned in his last email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience with professors, he's probably just overloaded with emails and either missed your messages or hasn't had the time or energy to reply, since it's probably not high on the list of priorities for him.

Assuming he's a professor at the university you attend, you could try just stopping by his office and hoping to catch him there. I did a similar thing once or twice during university and it was generally successful if the professor happened to be in. (If he's in a fancy office with a receptionist you could even ask the receptionist what hours he tends to be in the office, or ask them to pass along a note.)